# how to create signup form in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to create signup page in SugarCRM. after entering their details in the signup page all details have to insert in the SugarCRM database.

I written signup form using PHP but I don't know how to integrate it with SugarCRM. Kindly help me.

Tried Campaigns module but no use of this for my requirement.

Comment: Could you explain your goal a bit better, pelase? What are these people signing up for? Are you hoping to insert them as Contacts, or as Leads? Is this basic contact information or something more? Have you looked into the Web-to-Lead form?

Comment: Admin can create users and can give their status on the site. My object is, if someone wants to become the member to mysite, the have to register their details. Once the administrator approved their request, they can become the member of the site. That is, they can be able to login. For that only I need signup form. Using the modules(Contacts and Web-to-lead form) users can maintain their contacts only. The contact person will not become the member of the site. isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and comment, I understand that you want to have a web form that creates users in your SugarCRM system. This can be mostly done using the API, although the API doesn't seem to handle user passwords very well. I would approach it this way:

```
<?php
// leverage Asa Kusuma's excellent SugarCRM API Wrapper for PHP
$sugar = new \Asakusuma\SugarWrapper\Rest;
$sugar->setUrl('https://my.sugarsystem.com/service/v2/rest.php');
$sugar->setUsername('admin'); // ensure this user has the ability to create and manage users
$sugar->setPassword('password');
$sugar->connect();

$user_data = array(
  'user_name' => 'Sharmila',
  'first_name' => 'Sharmila',
  'last_name' => 'Smith',
  'email1' => 'ssmith@whatever.com',
  'is_admin' => '0',
  'status' => 'Active',
  'employee_status' => 'Active',
);

$new_user_id = $sugar->set('Users',$user_data);
```

You'll then need a mechanism to email this new user a link to the login page with instructions to click "Forgot Password?" and have a password re-set for them. They will not be able to log in until they've reset their password. Alternatively, you could create a logic hook or API extension to save the password via this API call or another one.